# How to make source folders visible in eclipse for PHP project?

Tags: php, eclipse, eclipse-pdt

I am having an issue with eclipse.

Currently my folders with sources are not visible if project has PHP nature in eclipse:
[image]
[image]

Is there any solution? Or should I reinstall my eclipse?

P.S. There might be a good guide how to setup a good Eclipse + PDT + PHPUnit env?

Comment: Menu Window->Show View->Php Explore

Comment: First screenshot is made from PHP Explorer.

Comment: And if you unfold the directory "protected", did not see anything?, Eclipse throws an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click "View Menu"(right-upper triangle of PHP Explorer), click "Group by namespaces".

Comment: Oh my God! You made my day! I want a babie from You :P